# how to remove the bottom left margin of side-panel in nsis script?

Tags: nsis

I need to make an installer by using nsis script. In custom screen there is a margin at the bottom left corner of side panel. It's caused by the line above the "Back","Next" and "Cancel" button. How to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ResHacker tool and edit appropriate .exe file with UI (User Interface).

UI files are stores in Contrib\UIs folder.

The UI file to edit depends on type of installer you use (classic vs Modern etc.)